# Is this question really a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I asked this question [How to use insert and select simultaneously?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89131/how-to-use-insert-and-select-simultaneously)

This question clearly asks for getting the id value after a row is inserted and it was closed for duplicate of this question [How to extract the last inserted row in SQL Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53071/how-to-extract-the-last-inserted-row-in-sql-server)

which says *When an insert statement is executed one or more rows is inserted into the table, is there any way to extract the last inserted row in SQL Server?*

Can anybody please tell me is this really a duplicate?

Comment: It is a duplicate and I should have searched the site for the duplicate before I answered your question.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson cool then delete your answer and I will delete my question also.I think its not good to keep duplicate questions

Comment: You have to unaccept first. It is not possible to delete an accepted answer.

Comment: Anyway, [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Comment: @MikaelEriksson unaccepted

Comment: What @AndriyM said. There's no need to be unaccepting or deleting anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's a duplicate.

> *This question clearly asks for getting the id value after a row is inserted*

The two main methods for doing this are using `SCOPE_IDENTITY` and the `OUTPUT` clause, both of which are described in the accepted answer.

Being closed as a duplicate just means the essence of your question has been asked and answered before.